# How to pass a string between two jsp pages?

Tags: string, jsp

I want to pass a string(username) between my two jsp pages,

Login.jsp and Details.jsp.

Please tell how it can be done?

```
I tries this in Login.Jsp
<html>
......
<%
session.setAttribute("key","value"); 
%>
.....
</html>

In Details.jsp
<html>
......
<%
session.getAttribute("key"); 
%>
.....
</html>

It showed  "NULL" as output.
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually after a login you should save the user data in sessions:

```
session.setAttribute("key","value");
```

and then access from other pages with

```
session.getAttribute("key");
```

if you need more information there's a lot around: http://www.jsptut.com/sessions.jsp

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to pass data from one webpage to another:

1. Put a form on `Login.jsp` and let it post to `Details.jsp`. This will post the values in the form to `Details.jsp`.
2. Redirect to `Details.jsp?username=ARJUN`. This will pass a variable to `Details.jsp` in te query string.
3. Put the username in a cookie. The cookie will be submitted to `Details.jsp` (and every other page), which makes it possible to determine the username in every page.
4. Put the username in the session. Similar to a cookie, but the session is stored on the server and associated with the user that is currently viewing your website.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

jsp1.jsp

```
    request.setAttribute("name",somevalue);

    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("jsp2.jsp");
    if (dispatcher != null){
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
```

jsp2.jsp

```
out.println(request.getAttribute("name"));
```

Answer (score 0):

First create servlet in write this code:
Here we can get the value using requet.getParameter("name"); here, name is textbox name of a previous page

`<%! String name=request.getParameter("name")%>`

`<% out.println("Welcome :"+name) %>`