# Pass parameter from one jsp to another without submitting

Tags: jsp

I have below text field which has alphanumberic data. And there will be a link to print form also. So whenever user click on that link, i am redirecting into another one jsp as mentioned below and also i would like to pass the mentioned alphanumberic text field, so that i could get the same in second jsp using get parameter.

```html
<!-- one of the text field -->
<label>IRno:</label><input type="text" name="irepno" id="irepno" class="inp" /><br><br>

<!--- print link -->
<a href="printcurreport.jsp?irepno=XXXX">Print Current Report</a>


<!--- second jsp -->
String repno = request.getParameter("irepno");
```

Please someone help me on how to do this

Comment: problem lies in the directory structure.Check whether both page lies in same dirctory or not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass a string between two jsp pages?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14728331/how-to-pass-a-string-between-two-jsp-pages)